# Badge style is broken when filtered to less than three

Tags: discussion, support, bug, design, badges

To reproduce, please select the *"All"* tab first and type keywords to filter out badges until there're less than three badges.

Two badges:

[image]

One badge:

[image]

No badge:

[image]

Comment: Related report on MSE: [Track/Select your next badge modal displays badges with incorrect width and positioning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367433/294055)

Comment: Thankfully it's *less* broken than it [was before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2HYF.png).

Comment: I can recreate the issue if I search for `arc`. However, if I search for `are`, the result is also two badges--but they display properly.

Comment: @DaveL17 Perhaps it's because you've got the `Enthusiast` badge, switch to the `All` tab and search again, and there'll be three badges.

Comment: @WenfangDu confirmed.  Interestingly, if I leave the filter set to `all` and search for `vis`, I get two badges and they're displayed properly (one of the resulting badges is an earned badge).

Comment: @DaveL17 I haven't earned any of these two badges, but if I repeat your steps, they're displayed normally as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Short answer**

A fixed `max-height` rule is at the heart of the issue. In the 6 to 8 weeks it takes to fix this, you can use the following overrides (apologies for using `!important`, but since SE's rulesets also use it, there is no other way):

```css
.popup._badge-selection {
  /* prevents vertical centering of the container */
  justify-content: start !important;
}

.popup._badge-selection .-list-item {
  /* removes content overflow */
  max-height: unset !important;
}

.popup .js-badge-list-container {
  /* keeps badge horizontal alignment */
  justify-content: center;
  /* removes badge vertical stretch */
  height: unset !important;
}
```

If anyone needs a quick JavaScript snippet, here it is:

```javascript
((_w, d) => {
  const style = d.createElement("style");
  d.head.append(style);
  const { sheet } = style;
  if (!sheet) return;
  [
    `.popup._badge-selection {
            justify-content: start !important;
        }`,
    `.popup._badge-selection .-list-item {
            max-height: unset !important;
            min-width: 256px;
        }`,
    `.popup .js-badge-list-container {
            justify-content: center;
            height: unset !important;
        }`,
  ].forEach(rule => sheet.insertRule(rule));
})(window, document);
```

---

**Long answer**

As the badge container can grow indefinitely, at some point the wrapped description text (which also has `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` of `16px` and `12px` respectively) starts to overflow the container. Here is an extract from the ruleset:

```css
.popup._badge-selection .-list-item {
  /* ...other rules */
  max-height: 128px;
}
```

Simply removing the rule would've solved the problem if not for the inline `height: 75%` set on the parent container, which makes an unrestrained badge container stretch the full height of the parent leading to:

[image: marshal badge container stretching the height]

One could add the [`ai-start`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/#align-items) class to prevent the flex item from stretching, but this obviously messes up the tile layout of multiple badges:

[image: messed up tile layout]

Another difficulty is presented by the fact badge filtering also uses inline styles (`display: none` <-> `display: block`) to show/hide badges depending on the query and not the [Stacks classes](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/display/#classes) (`d-none` and `d-block` respectively).

Given the above, the most reasonable thing to do is to `unset` the height override, but this presents another challenge since the `#popup-next-badge` container has a [`flex__center`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/#helpers) helper class which centers flex items on *both* [main](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_Axis) and [cross](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross_Axis) axis resulting in:

[image: centered flex items]

Fortunately, this is solved with the help of `justify-content` rule set to `start` (with `!important` as Stacks helper class also uses the rule) on the `.popup._badge-selection` container. Note that the inner `js-badge-list-container` needs another override back to `center` if you want the badges to be horizontally centered.

If you feel that it gets a bit too spacey when there are only one or two badges, a `min-width` rule on `._list-item` class set to `256px` or higher will help. In the end, you should get a result similar to this (for the ruleset summary see the short answer):

[image: fixed badge height and width]

Comment: You might want to post this on the related MSE post as well. I don't believe cross-posting answers on multiple Metas is an issue, though I'm not entirely sure about that.

Comment: @cigien if no one finds out that I am actually wrong about this, I'll likely make a post on MSE too, yeah, good idea. I still have to minify and uglify the snippet + can expand on a couple of points, so I don't think cross-posting will be an issue :)

Comment: I kinda had to double take on which site we're in when reading this answer.

Comment: I have nightmares of the W3C introducing a !veryimportant just for people trying to deal with this site.

Comment: @TylerH I propose we use `!important!`  and adding a `!` for each additional level of importance :)

Comment: @OlegValter Brilliant!