# Badge search in profile page renders incorrectly

Tags: bug, badges

After clicking on the "Choose which badge to track" icon
[[image]],

the "Select your next badge" modal pops up. And I typed "org" in the search bar. This provides only a single result which is incorrectly rendered.

Using Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64) on
MacBook Pro Version 11.5.2 Big Sur

[image]

Comment: Adding which browser and system you are seeing this would help. Seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPuca.png) in Chrome latest ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I updated the question to include browser and system @SurajRao

Comment: Already reported: [Badge style is broken when filtered to less than three](/q/409236/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon is it duplicate or a regression to [this ui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409236/badge-style-is-broken-when-filtered-to-less-than-three#comment855302_409236)? Either case still broke