# "Select your next badge" cells on Teams profile page too narrow

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams

When selecting a next badge to track in your profile page on Teams, the table cells are rather narrow:

[image]

This is how it looks like on main sites:

[image]

Comment: Oh not this bug again

Comment: Again? Has it been reported before? [I couldn't find it ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstack-overflow-for-teams%5D+%5Bbug%5D+badges+is%3Aq)

Comment: Strongly related to [Badge style is broken when filtered to less than three](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409236/badge-style-is-broken-when-filtered-to-less-than-three). Not a dupe, but related. zcoop's comment is even closer to this.

Comment: @Nick why not a dupe? Seems like a dupe to me. There is also a report on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367433/818993) that I posted, and that's why I'm asking

Comment: @RafaelTavares it is closer to yours. The reason I'd argue this isn't a dupe of the MSO post I've linked is that the MSO post _still leaves room_ for the columns that don't exist (as in, 2 populated columns and a single empty column). While in this case, there are precisely two columns. The issue while very similar and _potentially_ caused by the same thing, isn't identical, and we don't know the cause (at least not without putting in more effort than I care to)

Comment: @Nick ah, so it's related to the # of available badges, not Teams ...